# MySQL server not starting Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: server, mysql

I have been trying to install the mysql-server on my ubuntu server, but it just gives me this error when I type:

```
mysql
```

This is what I get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

If I check if it is on or not with:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

I get:

```
    ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-04-16 23:29:16 UTC; 5min ago
    Process: 474306 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited,         status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 23:29:16 amir-server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl -xe gives me:

```
Apr 16 23:38:54 amir-server systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 2666039 and the job result is failed.
```

I have tried reinstalling, no luck. What's funny is that the mysql server works on my other linux machine, but I need it to work on this one :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Edit]

```
pgrep -l mysql
```

does not return any processes

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

does not exist.

And if I do `mysqld` it gives me:

```
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-04-17T18:30:29.693043Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010101] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-04-17T18:30:29.710554Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 29346
2022-04-17T18:30:29.976620Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-17T18:30:30.038737Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
```

I did what @NioMarvin83 suggested. While installing, I got this:

```
MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see /etc/mysql/FROZEN for help.
```

This is what's inside `/etc/mysql/FROZEN`:

```
This MySQL or variant installation has entered "frozen mode". Maintainer
scripts will avoid making changes or starting the daemon until manually
released from this state. See /usr/share/doc/mysql-common/README for
general information about this mode.

In this particular case, an incompatible downgrade attempt has been
detected. This can be resolved in one of two ways:

1. Change the contents of /var/lib/mysql/ to contain database data that
is compatible with the currently installed MySQL or variant daemon
version. For example: you could restore from a backup. Alternatively you
could do a dump using a future version binary and then a restore using
the current version binary.

2. Switch to a MySQL or variant daemon version that is compatible with
the data currently in /var/lib/mysql/. For example, if you have
attempted a downgrade from mysql-server-5.7 to mysql-server-5.6, you
could "apt install mysql-server-5.7" again.

Please resolve this situation and only then remove the /etc/mysql/FROZEN
symlink. You can then run "dpkg-reconfigure <package>" where <package>
should usually be in the form <variant>-server-<version>.
```

Comment: Does `pgrep -l mysql` return any running processes?

Comment: The information in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` would be far more informative and point to the exact issue 

Comment: @matigo That file does not exist

Comment: @mchid No it does not

Comment: `mysql` is a client that wants to connect to `mysqld`, the database server. Have you installed `mysqld`? `pgrep mysqld`, `man mysqld`,

Comment: @waltinator yes I have `mysqld` gives me `mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

Comment: it also gives me ```Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.```

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator my bad, I will fix that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After many attempts, which ended only in my disappointment. However, the only thing I did before that was to install mysql-server with the command: sudo apt-get install mysql-server
I was trying to install and reinstall, upgrade and upgrade ubuntu, although I wasn't sure for my auto xloo part that it would help.

After many attempts and a lot of time it helped me - I fixed, "cleaning" each file associated with mysql, and reinstalling mysql-server:
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).